Data does not come in expo sqlite release version
I am trying to develop an application with React native expo. I can copy the existing database for Expo SQLite to the device memory, but I cannot pull the data. The strange thing is that I can pull data from the emulator in debug mode without any problems. Does anyone have any ideas about the error?
export const initializeDatabase = async () => {
  try {
    const dbPath = FileSystem.documentDirectory + dbName;
    const fileInfo = await FileSystem.getInfoAsync(dbPath);

    if (!fileInfo.exists) {
      // Veritabanı dosyası yoksa, assets klasöründen kopyalayın
      await FileSystem.makeDirectoryAsync(FileSystem.documentDirectory, { intermediates: true });
      await FileSystem.downloadAsync(
        Asset.fromModule(dbAsset).uri,
        dbPath
      );
      console.log('Veritabanı kopyalandı:', dbPath);
      Alert.alert('Bilgi', 'Veritabanı cihazınıza kopyalandı.', [{ text: 'Tamam' }]);
    } else {
      console.log('Veritabanı zaten mevcut:', dbPath);
    }

    // Veritabanını açın
    const db = SQLite.openDatabaseAsync(dbPath);
    console.log('Veritabanı açıldı.');
    return db;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Veritabanı başlatma hatası:', error);
    Alert.alert('Hata', 'Veritabanı başlatılamadı.', [{ text: 'Tamam' }]);
    throw error;
  }
};//This code is in app.js

and
 const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const [gununKelimesi, setGununKelimesi] = useState({ ingilizce: '', turkce: '' });
  useEffect(() => {
    const setupDatabase = async () => {
      try {
        const db = await initializeDatabase();
        setDatabase(db);
      } catch (error) {
        // Hata zaten initializeDatabase içinde ele alındı
      } finally {
        setIsLoading(false);
        const kelime = await database.getFirstAsync("SELECT İngilizce, Türkçe FROM jarguru ORDER BY RANDOM()");
      
        setGununKelimesi({ ingilizce: kelime.İngilizce, turkce: kelime.Türkçe });
      }
    };

    setupDatabase();
  }, []);

  if (isLoading) {
    // Veritabanı başlatılırken yükleme göstergesi gösterin
    return (
      <View style={stil.loadingContainer}>
        <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#0000ff" />
      </View>
    );
  }//This is the code on the screen where I want to show the data.

but the data does not come in the release version
